# A way to close a strategy based on 2 parameters

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to code a strategy in pine where in I want to close a strategy after some bars but in the duration of the bars completion I want to have a stop loss as well. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strategy.enty()` with `when` parameter and `stategy.exit()` function with `stop` and `loss` parameters.

Play-around with this script, by going in the first bars on your chart (set GOLD symbol, 1D res):

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy0", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = 1)

//labels for bars
if (bar_index <= 15)
    label.new(bar_index, 300, tostring(bar_index) )

strategy.entry("EN", strategy.long, when= bar_index == 0) // enter at bar #0
strategy.close("EN", when=bar_index == 15) // close at bar #15


strategy.exit("EN_EXIT", from_entry = "EN", stop = 312)  // set stop and loss here
```

Use
https://kodify.net/tradingview/orders/strategy-entry/
https://kodify.net/tradingview/orders/percentage-stop/
as a reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand what I was doing wrong earlier.